# Elimination reaction with 1,2-dibromo-4-methylcyclohexane

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution, elimination

I was doing a question from a practice exercise on the topic of elimination reactions and alkene synthesis. It is shown below:

[image]

I predicted that the product would be 1,2-diiodo-4-methylcyclohexane because I thought the reaction conditions favoured substition with iodide via the $\ce {S_N2}$ mechanism. Firstly, iodide is a rather good nucleophile and secondly, the substrate is a secondary alkyl halide. Even if it was not $\ce {S_N2}$, I would expect perhaps $\ce {S_N1}$ since iodide is a rather weak base and the conditions do not seem to favour elimination. However, the answer provided is very interestingly, 4-methylcyclohexene. Would someone kindly enlighten me on where I went wrong?

Comment: I think they should have mentioned heat in the question. 1,2-diiodo when heated undergo elimination to form alkenes.

Comment: Iodide is an even better leaving group than bromide. So if anything is to happen, it has to be more complicated than a simple substitution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Dehalogenation of vicinal dihalides by iodide ion occurs stereospecifically and
>   concertedly via an $\mathrm{E2}$ mechanism. An anti-coplanar arrangement of both bromine atoms is required (see [diagram](https://image.slidesharecdn.com/08alkesynth-120625210757-phpapp01/95/08-alkesynth-23-728.jpg?cb=1340658567) below):

[image: diagram]

Since, the given compound is a 1,2-*trans*-dibromocyclohexane, two bromo groups  can arrange in 1,2-*anti*-diaxial positions in one of chair confirmations, fulfilling the requirement. It won't be possible if it'd have been a 1,2-*cis*-dibromocyclohexane.

Reference: Structure & Synthesis of Alkenes (Chapter 7): Leroy G. Wade, *Organic Chemistry*; 8th Edn, Pearson Education Limited: Harlow, Essex, UK, 2014.

Comment: Here it would also good to redraw important parts yourself.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Conformation of 1,2 dibromo,4-tertbutyl cyclohexane]

As you can see from above mechanism the dibromo needs to be in an axial positions for elimination

Comment: I see a set of structures and a textual description posted as an image, but not the mechanism itself. Please post text as text, not a screenshot, whenever possible. Also, if you are using a third-party source, also add a proper reference and format the copied part accordingly (e.g. as a block qoute with `>`).